# What is "Free Space Notifier"?

Tags: kubuntu, startup, services

I'm running KUbuntu 10.04.1 - I click on "System Settings" from the KMenu, click on the advanced tab, and start up "Service Manager".  In the lower pane, I see "Free Space Notifier" is running.

**Update:** It might be a monitor for the free disk space in your home partition.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Maybe it monitors the free disk space in my home partition??  [Link to Fedora Package with the same name](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/applications/Free%20Space%20Notifier?_csrf_token=7d94daa5b8a1cb5c878dfd3f83aa1d5efd5fc557)

Comment: I edited your question for you to update it to the real question. Note that people are not going to read the comments on the main page.

Comment: @Javier, I removed my other comment & undid your changes. I'm still not sure if the Fedora package is related to the Ubuntu package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [package description](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/kde/freespacenotifier), it monitors free disk space on the Home partition and warns you on low disk space.

> KDE Daemon module for low disk space
>
> This is a small KDED module that
>   monitors free disk space on the home
>   directory partition and shows a
>   warning dialog when it runs too low,
>   with a configurable limit and the
>   possibility to postpone.